# How To Change UICollectionView Cell Background Colour From Outside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uicollectionview

I have a pie chart that is clickable, each section represents a cell inside the UICollectionView. On clicking a pie section I want to change the background colour of the cell it corresponds to. I am using the following but nothing is happening.

```
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:index];

[[self.collectionCategories cellForItemAtIndexPath:path] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

}
```

Any ideas, Thanks.

Comment: Is this code in the same controller that has the collection view?

Comment: Yeah, it just doesn't seem to want to interact or make a change. I have checked to make sure that they are connected and it is and I have also tried changing the cell colour (it works) when the cell is created.

Comment: Have you checked (with logging or the debugger) that [self.collectionCategories cellForItemAtIndexPath:path] is returning a cell?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did that and it has helped to solve the issue. I needed to use the following instead:    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

Comment: I was just about to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you create your index path. You should be doing it like so (assuming that you have only one section),

```
 NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0];
```

The indexPath for a table view or collection view needs to specify both the section and the row. If you log the index path created by the above method, you will see that it's length is 2, whereas the way you originally did it, the length is only 1.

Comment: Thanks, yeah just noticed this a few minutes ago. You are correct after I added the above it was picking up on the cell.